# Does elegant way exist to convert double to long long?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, double, long-long

I want to get `integer part` of `double`. But this way does not work for me:

```
double param, fractpart, intpart;

param = 3.14159265;
fractpart = modf (param , &intpart);
printf ("%f = %f + %f \n", param, intpart, fractpart);
```

It is due to the fact, that `double integer` may have `e-notation`. For example, `3.41e10` is correct double number.

My test cases is:

- double -> long long
- 234343.0 -> 234343
- 3.41e10 -> 34100000000
- 19.999999999 -> 19
- -10.1 -> -10
- -0.0000001 -> 0

Is there some beautiful way to complete my task?

Comment: Are you talking about converting strings containing floating point numbers to `long long` or actual `double` variables?

Comment: @Columbo, Actually, I have double variable. But, if you need to cast double -> string -> long long, it is good too.

Comment: XY problem? Why should the e-notation matter?

Comment: @cppguy, may be it is XY problem. My main task it transform double variable to integer array (this array is used for storing Big Numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truncating your result by implicit conversion should do:

```
std::cout << (long long)234343.0     << '\n'
          << (long long)3.41e10      << '\n'
          << (long long)19.999999999 << '\n'
          << (long long)-10.1        << '\n'
          << (long long)-0.0000001   << '\n';
```

Should, on your machine, output

```
234343
34100000000
19
-10
0
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c43a0c3af288db94).

Comment: In general one should avoid the old-style casts. In this case you want `static_cast<long long>()`